# Estimate correlation with mixed frequency data

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation

I want to compare two mutual funds.

I have fund A's weekly performance data. But for fund B, the data is less reliable. For 60% of the time, I can get hold of their weekly data, but other periods, they only publish month end data.

For example, their fund valuation data could look like below

```
date             A      B
2010-01-02      1.0    1.0
2010-01-09      1.04    
2010-01-16      1.07   
2010-01-23      1.04
2010-01-30      0.97   0.95
2010-02-06      1.03   1.05
2010-02-13      1.10   1.08
2010-02-20      1.15   
2010-02-27      1.11   1.07
```

Is there a good approach to estimate their correlation? The easiest way is to down sample A to monthly and calculate monthly correlation, but that throws away many valid data of B.

Comment: Which correlation? Autocorrelation or cross-correlation?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, correlation between the two series

Comment: You really need to add more context, specifics for this to be answerable

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks. Updated. What do I need to do to ask for reopening it?

Comment: I have reopened it. Maybe look at the tag [tag:unevenly-spaced-time-series] or even add it!